# PouchDB not working in Chrome (kind of)

Tags: pouchdb

I am trying to make PouchDB working for two days now - some simple stuff works some doesn't.

It was hard to isolate the cause but I finally managed to isolate one problem - is it problem 
with IndexDB destroying database and creating again OR promises implementation in PouchDB I don't have a clue.

Anyway - this code below works in Firefox till the end but in Chorme gets only to "Creating database..." and stops without any warning (under debugger never gets to "Posting record")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>

<body>

<script src="lib/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb-nightly.js"></script>

<script>
    new PouchDB('test')
        .then(function (db) {
            console.log("Destroying database.. ");
            return db.destroy()
        })
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Creating database.. ");
            return new PouchDB('test');
        })
        .then(function (db) {
            console.log("Posting record.. ");
            return db.post({name: 'name'});
        })
        .then(function(info){
            console.log("Checking id of inserted record: " + info.id);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any workaround ?

I need "destroy database->then create new->then do some stuff" flow of operations that works every time in every browser - I tried with promises, with callbacks - either gets result like in code sample or IndxedDB error 11...

Comment: No problem here, creating and deleting databases in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There's something funky going on in your promise chain, but here's a workaround that does just fine:

```
new PouchDB('test')
        .then(function (db) {
            console.log("Destroying database.. ");
            return db.destroy();
        })
        .then(function () {
            console.log("Creating database.. ");
            return new PouchDB('test').then(function (db) {
                console.log("Posting record.. ");
                return db.post({name: 'name'});
            })
            .then(function(info){
                console.log("Checking id of inserted record: " + info.id);
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
        });
```

Output:

`Destroying database..
Creating database..
Posting record..
Checking id of inserted record: 0613FFBA-518F-4F20-A1DD-D18E59A4340B`

Just to be safe, though, I've filed [an issue](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/1972) on PouchDB.